# Hybrid Graphics: how to launch a game from the second card. two Identical nvidia cards

Tags: nvidia, graphics, hybrid

I was wondering if it's possible to launch a full-screen program from a second graphics card, while keeping the first one as a main for the desktop. I have two identical nVidia GeForce GT 750M in my laptop and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on it.

To install drivers was already a problem (got desktop login loop problem), but managed somehow, they both are on and seen by the system.

The only problem now it that the only one card is being used. And I would like to parallelize their work somehow. For example, I was wondering if I can make them working one for desktop, one for the full-screen program or something like that.

I tried Nvidia X Server so far, but I don't see any options to parallelize their work there. Maximum I can do is to switch from one card to another permanently. 
Thanks.

Comment: "I have two identical nVidia GeForce GT 750M in my laptop" Really? Are you sure you don't have one Nvidia and one Intel GPU? Provide the output of `sudo lshw -C display`. If you have an Intel chip also, you CANNOT use them at the same time, one is for performance and one is for battery life.

Comment: Yes, i'm pretty sure, the command gives two `product: GK107M [GeForce GT 750M]` with `bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0` and `bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0` <br/> P.s. wanted to insert the whole out but struggle now with comments formating =) Sorry, first day in the forum.

Comment: But just in case, whole output      ` -display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK107M [GeForce GT 750M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:35 memory:d3000000-d3ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:5000(size=128) memory:d4080000-d40fffff`

Comment: And the second half      *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GK107M [GeForce GT 750M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:36 memory:d2000000-d2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128)